# How to trigger backspage key event when button click java

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, keyevent, buttonclick

How can I trigger backspace key press event when button click.

```
private void doClick(char type)
{
   jTextField1.dispatchEvent(new KeyEvent(jTextField1, KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, System.currentTimeMillis(),KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK, KeyEvent.VK_7, type));
   jTextField1.dispatchEvent(new KeyEvent(jTextField1, KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, System.currentTimeMillis(),KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK, KeyEvent.VK_UNDEFINED, type));
   jTextField1.dispatchEvent(new KeyEvent(jTextField1, KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, System.currentTimeMillis(),KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK, KeyEvent.VK_7, type));
}
```

Im using this method to add one character when button click. Is there any mechanism to trigger backspace key press event like this.

Comment: That seems like a lot of work for little gain...why not just get the text and remove the character?

Comment: I think it is easy to do because it simplifies the thinking of the algorithm.

Comment: Okay, then you have a problem, `KEY_TYPED` comes after `KEY_RELEASED`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, before I answer the question, because I believe the approach is dirty, here are two, similar, concepts...

You could make use of the [`Action` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), which would allow you to define self-contained units for work.  These could be abstract to do the heavy lifting, in the particular case of inserting new values, but this demonstrates the use case of removing a character...

```
public class BackspaceAction extends AbstractAction {

    private JTextField field;

    public BackspaceAction(JTextField field) {
        putValue(NAME, "Back-space");
        this.field = field;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String text = field.getText();
        if (!text.isEmpty()) {
            int position = field.getCaretPosition();
            if (position > 0) {
                text = text.substring(0, position - 1) + text.substring(position);
                field.setText(text);
                field.setCaretPosition(Math.max(position - 1, 0));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Or through use the `Document` itself...

```
public class BackspaceAction extends AbstractAction {

    private JTextField field;

    public BackspaceAction(JTextField field) {
        putValue(NAME, "Back-space");
        this.field = field;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Document doc = field.getDocument();
        if (doc.getLength() > 0) {
            int position = field.getCaretPosition();
            if (position > 0) {
                try {
                    doc.remove(position - 1, 1);
                    field.setCaretPosition(Math.max(position - 1, 0));
                } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Which would simply instantiated using something like...

```
JButton back = new JButton(new BackspaceAction(field));
```

If you're hell bent on trying to get into the nitty gritty low layers of the API, then something like....

```
char value = (char)8;
field.dispatchEvent(new KeyEvent(field, KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0, KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE, value));
field.dispatchEvent(new KeyEvent(field, KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0, KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE, value));
field.dispatchEvent(new KeyEvent(field, KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0, KeyEvent.VK_UNDEFINED, value));
```

might work.  I say might, as this does work on Windows 7, but I make no guarantee if it will work on any other platforms or versions of Windows

Now, for me, I can look at the other two `Action`s and see what they are trying to do, I look at the key event approach and begin to scratch my head wondering why, but that's just me...

Answer (score 0):

All Swing components have default Actions to perform this type of functionality. You may want to consider using the default "backspace Action" to do this.

If so then check out the [ActionMapAction](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/06/action-map-action/) class is a simple wrapper class that will allow you to easily use the default Action for the component by creating the Action for you. For example the code would be:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
Action backSpace = new ActionMapAction("Backspace", textField, "delete-previous");
backSpace.putValue(AbstractAction.MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_B);
JButton backSpaceButton = new JButton(backSpace);
```

You can use the Action with JButtons, JMenuItems. Make use of reusable code to leverage existing Actions of the Swing components.